# Variaveis em Node JS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express.js, request

queria entender mais o conceito das variáveis em NODE. 
Tentei fazer um simples code para ler um json da internet. 
Criei uma variavel para receber o nome do titulo, mas depois de setado, ele retorna para o valor antigo. 
Estou começando agora e queria entender mais sobre como as variaveis funcionam no node. 
 
Obrigado!

```
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let encryptTitle = 0
    request.get({
        url: 'https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts',
        json: true
    },
         (error, response, body) => {
            encryptTitle = body[1].title
            console.log(encryptTitle) // retorna Post 2
    });

    console.log(encryptTitle) // retorna 0
    res.send("Hello Worlds")
})


app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

A variável está correta, o problema é que no JavaScript as tarefas de IO (network, file, etc) são executadas de forma assíncrona. O problema aqui é que o log que retorna "0" é executado durante a request. Já o log que retorna "Post 2" é executado apenas quando a tua request é concluída, bem depois do log que retorna 0 ser executado.

O problema é relacionado a parte assíncrona do JavaScript e essencial para dominar a linguagem. Recomendo a leitura das varias formas para escrever esse código, no geral callbacks, promises e async são utilizados.

Bons estudos!

Comment: Teria alguma sugestão de material para eu estudar? Ou até mesmo o  codigo funcionando para eu dar uma olhada?

Comment: A forma simples seria continuar escrevendo código dentro do teu callback (ali onde tem o comentário de retorna 2). O problema é que logo logo o código vai ficar não manutenível e daí vale a pena olhar as formas que comentei.